# How do we get a time duration in C++ since a given year?

Tags: c++, c++-chrono, ctime

How do we get a time duration in C++ since a given year?
Can we do it with ctime or should we use chrono as well?

Comment: One first has to nail down more details in the question:  Since the beginning of the year?  Or the end of the year?  In what time zone should the beginning (for example) of the year be defined?  UTC?  Europe/Moscow?

Comment: Since the beginning of the year.

Answer (score 3):

With `<chrono>` in C++20:

```
using namespace std::chrono;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

const auto start = sys_days {2010y / January / 1};
const auto now = system_clock::now();

const auto dur = now - start;
```

`dur` is now a `std::chrono::duration`.

You can use it as is, or you could cast it to a specific unit, e.g.

```
long ms = duration_cast<milliseconds>(dur).count()
```

Comment: Just to clarify, this gets the time since the start of the year 00:00:00 UTC.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done quite simply with C++20 and the `<chrono>` library. Assuming you want to know the duration between now and 2000/01/01, you can do:

```cpp
using namespace std::literals::chrono_literal;

auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
auto delta = now - std::chrono::sys_days(2000y/1/1);

std::cout << delta;
```

Note a lot of `chrono`'s feature are not implemented in some major compilers, you might use Howard Hinnant(author of `<chrono>`)'s [Date library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date).

A demo using the `date` library: https://godbolt.org/z/ar8P6zY7E, you should be able to simply swap the namespace once the `<chrono>` library was fully implemented.

---

Edit, turns out I forgot to use C++20 flag for my demo, with it on: https://godbolt.org/z/5b7bEf6sf

Comment: Just to clarify, this gets the time since the start of the year 00:00:00 UTC.